# emacs --daemon crashing after closing emacsclient -c

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, emacs

I start emacs daemon with the following commnad.

```
$ emacs --daemon
```

This seems to work. 
After this I start emacs client as follows

```
$ emacsclient -c
```

Whenever I close the emacsclient, the server also stops with the following error.

```
X protocol error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) on protocol request 42
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Fatal error (6)zsh: abort
```

I have not found any information about this problem. Is there a way around this?

Comment: how do you close the emacs client? With C-x C-c or C-x 5 0

Comment: I've tried both, the problem remains the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug, [FS#32423: emacsclient consistently crashes emacs](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32423?project=1). The bug has been [reported to the Emacs authors](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-11/msg00048.html). It is compounded by a [Gtk bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715). The following workarounds are reported to work:

- Downgrading to Emacs 24.1 (instead of 24.2).
- Downgrading Glib to 2.32 (instead of 2.34).
- Compiling Emacs without Gtk (`--with-x-toolkit=lucid`).
- Starting the daemon with no X connection available (try `DISPLAY= emacs --daemon`).

No actual solution seems to be known at this time.

This isn't something you can fix on your own unless you're a programmer and you're familiar with the technologies involved. Your best bet is to use one of the workarounds and keep watching the bug reports for a fix.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've tested option 4 with recent (ie: 24.3 release) builds of Emacs, and it does not work. I don't have GTK3 as an option, sadly, but GTK2 exhibits this behaviour irrespective of the DISPLAY state on launch; as near as I can tell from a read of the GTK bug, it's an issue with the client state tracking.

Comment: Emacs 24.5 has it too but at least the message seems to point to a solution: `Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.`

Comment: 2020 and still an issue. And you cant compile in xwidgets without gtk. Painful.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Is it possible to compile `GccEmacs` with `--with-x-toolkit=lucid` flag?

Comment: @alper yes it is.

Comment: discouragingly, this is _still_ a problem in 2023; shutting down the ssh connection that `emacsclient -c` is being forwarded through will crash the remote emacs process. on the gtk side, this is being tracked at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2315 (they seem to have a handle on what causes it as of 2022, but not on how to cleanly fix it).